# A message body reader for Java class Foo, and Java type class Foo , and MIME media type text/html; charset=utf-8 was not found

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I am using Jersey service to call a service and i am getting this exception. Any help appreciated. And this problem is intermittent.

```
[|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse|_ThreadID=99;_ThreadName=quartzScheduler_Worker-5;|A message body reader for Java class com.xxx.ResonseObjectView, and Java type class com.xxx.ResonseObjectView, and MIME media type text/html; charset=utf-8 was not found|#]

[|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse|_ThreadID=99;_ThreadName=quartzScheduler_Worker-5;|The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyMessageBodyWorker
  com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyListMessageBodyWorker
|#]
```

> Using @XmlRootElement for Response POJO

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ResponseObjectView extends BaseRestObject

@XmlRootElement
public class BaseRestObject
```

> This is how service is being called

```
  protected ClientResponse executeRequest( String resourceUrl, Object argument )
  {
    if( argument instanceof SecureToken )
    {
      SecureToken parameter = (SecureToken)  argument ;
      parameter.setSecurityToken( MD5Hash.hash( parameter.getHashableAttribute(), salt ) );
    }
    return this.buildWebResource( resourceUrl ).type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE ).accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE ).post( ClientResponse.class, argument );
  }
```

> This is service which consumes and produces MediaType JSON

```
  @POST
  @Path( "/test.biws" )
  @Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
  @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
  public ResponseObjectView request( RequestObjectView request, @Context UriInfo uriInfo )
  {
    ................
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: I'm guessing there is an error on the error side which causes an html error response from the server. Possible internal server error. I'm thinking if you print the status of the request, will be be 500. If this is the case try to debug the problem by writing an `ExceptionMapper<Exception>` and log the error. Or check the server to see if a stack trace is already logged. The error you are currently seeing is a client side error, because it can't find a reader for html, meaning the response type is html

Comment: Why would it be html if i have @Produces MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ?

Comment: Reread my comment... Because of a server generated response, due to unhandled/unmapped exception. Print the response as a string. See what it is